# Can Files transferred in COM programming?

Tags: com, atl

Can COM supports file transferring from  Client to server and vice versa?
if So, Can I get some sample code ?

Thanks
Pavan

Comment: What do you mean specifically by "file transferring"? You can transfer pretty much anything in DCOM with a stream or a SAFEARRAY of bytes. There might be a different maximum size for each, though.

Comment: @Medinoc, I mean to exchange of files(it can be Images, txt or application files). I am writing a POC to report issues from the client where Server has business logic to create issue... Where I need to provide option to attach files

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't support files transmission, but you have a couple of options.

You could pass a file path as `BSTR` (the file could be inaccessible to the server depending on the file access restrictions in the filesystem and the server process privileges). You could pass `IStream` interface to the server and feed the file data via `IStream`.